# Is object inside object or object equal object the same in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, object, curly-braces

Is this piece of code:

```
const a = { aProp: 1 };
const c = {
    b: { a }
};
```

the same as this piece of code:

```
const a = { aProp: 1 };
const c = {
    b: a
};
```

?

I mean will `c` have exactly the same properties in both cases? And what technical differences are there in the code?

Thank you.

Comment: `console.log(c)`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a brief: **no**.

`b: { a }` is a **shorthand** for `b: { a: a }` so it will result in a nested property:

```
const c = {
   b: { a: { aProp: 1 } },
};
```

In your second case:

```
b: a,
```

it's just a normal assignment, which will result in:

```
const c = {
    b: { aProp: 1 },
};
```

Comment: I would be grateful for the reference to read about this: `b: { a }`. Thank you.

Comment: @oobarbazanoo it's called Object Literal Shorthand Syntax. It was implemented in ES6. You can read more e.g. here: https://www.sitepoint.com/es6-enhanced-object-literals/